# Where can I read Manusmriti along with all its commentaries in English?

Tags: scripture, translation-request, manu-smriti, resource

Manusmriti has [more than six](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manusmriti#Commentaries) commentaries so far (Bhāruci, Medhātithi, Govindarāja, Kullūka, Nārāyana, Sarvajnanarayana, Nandana, Raghavananda, Ramacandra). Only Medhatithi's commentary which has been translated to English is [available online](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi) as per my knowledge. Where can I read the other commentaries in English?

Comment: I think all commentaries are not translated into English.

Comment: *Manusmriti with the Commentary of Medhatithi* in English: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi

Comment: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu.htm George Bühler, translator